# why this function is in all of the object even though i only mentioned it in one

Tags: javascript, oop, javascript-objects

I've added a method `calcAge` to `jonas`, but why is it working for `matilda`?

```js
const Person = function (firstName, birthYear) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.birthYear = birthYear;
};

const jonas = new Person('jonas', 1991);
const matilda = new Person('Matilda', 2017);

jonas.__proto__.calcAge = function () {
  console.log(2037 - this.birthYear);
};
jonas.calcAge(); // 46
matilda.calcAge(); // 20
```

Comment: `__proto__` is a property which accesses the object's prototype. When you add a method to it makes that method available to all other instances of the prototype. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

Comment: i got it if you really wanna put property in only one object then it dosent make sense to put that in prototype i got it

Comment: i am new in javascript and still learing it Objects in js work quite diffrent then other langs

Comment: If you only want it on one instance, remove `__proto__`? `jonas.calcAge = function ...`

Comment: got it brother its working that way

Answer (score 0):

You added the method to **proto** which all objects inherit from. so jonas.**proto** and matilda.**proto** reference the same thing. You can think of it like a family tree.

example: carl.mom and jane.mom if carl and jane are brother and sister. mom is the same person.

hope this makes sense.